# Find a possible polynomial under certain conditions

Tags: trigonometry

The polynomial of degree $5$, $P(x)$ has leading coefficient $1$, has roots of multiplicity $2$ at $x=5$ and $x=0$, and a root of multiplicity $1$ at $x=-5$.

Find a possible formula for $P(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the polynomial can be factored into its roots. Use its multiciplities to find out the formula of $P(x)=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4)(x-r_5)$, then multiply it out.

Comment: Why would he multiply it out? You have essentially given him the answer. Boo. You should endeavor to give hints rather than answers for elementary problems.

Comment: @MPW I don't see how giving a hint could be possible in an easy problem. If he knows the definition of multiplicity, then the problem should be trivial.

Comment: It's *always* better to give a trail of simple clues and let OP put them together to make a discovery. Some hints could be: (1) $P(x)$ has a root at $r$ iff $(x-r)$ is a factor of $P$; (2) $P$ and $cP$ have the same degree for any constant $c\neq0$; (3) the multiplicity $m$ of the root $r$ corresponds to the exponent $m$ of the factor $(x-r)^m$.

Comment: I just mean to say, you can take advantage of a pedagogical opportunity here instead of supplying just an answer, since this is such an elementary question.